# Why does running the Get-CsOnlineUser command in C# return "An error has occurred which PowerShell cannot handle. A remote session might have ended."

Tags: c#, powershell

I've installed this package: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0

And am able to run commands like `Get-CsTenant | Select-Object DisplayName`

But when I try to run this command: `Get-CsOnlineUser | Select-Object  UserPrincipalName, DisplayName, Name`

With this C# code

```
PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
            try
            {
                using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
                {
                    runspace.Open();
                    powershell.Runspace = runspace;
                    powershell.AddScript(@".\Connect.ps1");
                    powershell.Invoke();

                    var testOne = powershell.AddScript("Get-CsTenant | Select-Object DisplayName").Invoke().ToList();
                    var testTwo = powershell.AddScript("Get-CsOnlineUser | Select-Object  UserPrincipalName, DisplayName, Name").Invoke().ToList();
                }
                return testTwo;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var errors = powershell.Streams.Error.ToList();
                return null;
            }
```

I get this error message
[An error has occurred which PowerShell cannot handle. A remote session might have ended.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV7Ww.png)

[More error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPjlw.png)

When running these commands in the powershell interface with the same credentials they work fine.

Comment: It appears the fix won't be coming until version 3.0.0 - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/authenticating-with-an-access-token-connect-microsoftteams/m-p/2233794

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to add the following to the `PropertyGroup` element in the Project File:

```
<EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>true</EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>
```

I believe this is required for remote PowerShell usage after .NET 5.0.